# Is there any franchise which officially releases animated mangas?

Tags: anime-production, manga-production

Many fans create animated mangas using the images of the mangas and giving them some animation and music of background. It looks pretty look, and sometimes it's more fun than the mangas themselves. This is easier to create than actual anime, and I was wondering if some franchise actually create products like this officially.

Is there any franchise which officially releases animated mangas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Yes, even with voice acting, but may not cover the series completely.** This kind of work is known as **ボイスコミック・ボイコミ (Voice Comic)** in Japan.

The publisher Shueisha started the idea in 2007 with the brand "VOMIC" (**VO**ICE + CO**MIC**). They first published it on their own site, then as a mini-corner on the TV, and finally with the ease of internet accessibility, on video streaming sites such as Nico Nico Douga (NND) and YouTube.

Example:

- *Naruto* (NND, 4 chapters: [1](https://www.nicovideo.jp/watch/so15118078), [2](https://www.nicovideo.jp/watch/so15271438), [3](https://www.nicovideo.jp/watch/so15337565), [4](https://www.nicovideo.jp/watch/so15412915))
- *Haikyuu!!* (NND, 4 chapters: [1](https://www.nicovideo.jp/watch/so20263316), [2](https://www.nicovideo.jp/watch/so20330891), [3](https://www.nicovideo.jp/watch/so20378066), [4](https://www.nicovideo.jp/watch/so20451474))
- *Sakamoto Days* (YouTube, [3 chapters](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JTzoq1njKdM))

Most of them are not complete series because it is more for promotional purposes.

More official voice comics:

- Shueisha VOMIC Channel ([NND Channel](https://ch.nicovideo.jp/vomic), ['VOMIC' tag on NND](https://www.nicovideo.jp/tag/VOMIC))
- Kadokawa Official Channel ([YouTube Channel](https://www.youtube.com/user/KadokawaOfficial/search?query=%E3%83%9C%E3%82%A4%E3%82%B9%E3%82%B3%E3%83%9F%E3%83%83%E3%82%AF))
- Kadokawa Anime ([YouTube Channel](https://www.youtube.com/c/KADOKAWAanime/search?query=%E3%83%9C%E3%82%A4%E3%82%B9%E3%82%B3%E3%83%9F%E3%83%83%E3%82%AF))
- KODANSHA Books&Comics ([YouTube Channel](https://www.youtube.com/user/KODANSHAcojp/search?query=%E3%83%9C%E3%82%A4%E3%82%B9%E3%82%B3%E3%83%9F%E3%83%83%E3%82%AF)
- JUMP COMICS CHANNEL ([YouTube Channel](https://www.youtube.com/c/jumpchannel/search?query=%E3%83%9C%E3%82%A4%E3%82%B9%E3%82%B3%E3%83%9F%E3%83%83%E3%82%AF), [YouTube Playlist #1](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLMyQxaghEY1Fe6bUvggB1V_CT1ErASFY6), [YouTube Playlist #2](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLMyQxaghEY1EQ1UuYMQEroXMCpOJhFQi9))

---

Reference:

- VOMIC - [Japanese Wikipedia](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/VOMIC), [3rd-party English translation](https://second.wiki/wiki/vomic)
- [YouTubeで急増中の「ボイスコミック」とは？　若者の漫画需要拡大に新たな可能性](https://realsound.jp/tech/2020/02/post-497760.html) (Japanese)

Comment: Great answer. I wish they would make one for One Punch Man! There are some unofficial ones pretty cool